# AutoCAD Implement cad drawing into GeoJSON on OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, autocad

How can I put my AutoCAD drawing into OpenStreetMap?

I tried AutoCAD Map 3D but I can't somehow put it in my desired location.

by the way, here is my desired location in openstreetmap
[OSM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuNH9.png)
and my autocad drawing I wish to put it in openstreetmap as a GEOJSON
[Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lifL6.png)

Comment: Try to use the tools that are meant for editing OSM like JOSM.

Comment: @scai but it cant deal with autocad files

Comment: A first step could be to export your drawing as an image so that you can overlay it on the map.

Comment: @PabloUmald Right, because usually there is no reason to import CAD files into OSM. Maybe you should explain the reasons for your strange approach.

Comment: @scai yes, im trying to put my drawing into openstreetmap as a GeoJSON so i can use leaflet for my app to use my drawing in OSM interface

Comment: Showing GeoJSON in Leaflet should be easy.

Comment: @scai yes yes but my very question is, how can I convert my drawing into GeoJSON

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this doc: https://github.com/open-indoor/openindoor6/blob/main/AUTOCAD.md

Mainly use ogr2ogr to convert dxf to geojson, and to fix GPS location.

OpenIndoor web app aims to render the result in a 3D scene.
https://app.openindoor.io
Just drag and drop your geojson files in it.